# ASP.NET MVC code modal popup not sending parameter to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, popupwindow

I am trying to present Organization Details in a partial view in a Bootstrap Modal. After a day of reading/watching tutorials I am stumped.

Organizations are loaded into a Table and there is a View option on each row. The table has an `id="OrganizationGrid"`

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="OrganizationGrid">
  <thead>
    <tr style="color:#126E75; background-color:lightcyan">
      <th style=" width:5%">
        @Html.ActionLink("ID", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.IDSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
      </th>
      <th style=" width:25%">
        @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
      </th>
      <th style=" width:25%">
        Parent Org
      </th>
      <th style=" width:10%; text-align:center">
        Website
      </th>
      <th style="width:25%">
        Comment
      </th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="3" style=" width:10%; text-align:center">Action</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr class=" table-light">
      <td style="text-align:left">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:left">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:left">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentOrg.Name)
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <a href=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.Website) target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-globe" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"></i>
                                    </a>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:left">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
          <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="details" href="javascript:;">View</a>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
          <i class="fas fa-trash" style="color:red"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My understanding is that it triggers the JavaScript function which is currently residing at the bottom of the same page:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#OrganizationGrid .details").click(function() {
      var organizationId = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Organizations/Details",
        data: '{organizationId: "' + organizationId + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response) {
          $("#partialModal").find(".modal-body").html(response);
          $("#partialModal").modal('show');
        },
        failure: function(response) {
          alert(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function(response) {
          alert(response.responseText);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

I inserted a break in the controller to see if ajax was passing the organizationId but it is not.  This is the Controller Details Action method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(int organizationId)
    {

        var organization = _context.Organizations
            .Include(o => o.ParentOrg).Where(p=>p.Id == organizationId);


        if (organization == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return PartialView("_Details", organization);
    }
```

If I hard code organizationId in the Controller the popup loads with the correct information BUT if I hard code organizationId in the JavaScript function it still passes a null value to the controller.  Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the JavaScript function and specifically the syntax of the data attribute in ajax.  Corrected solution is as follows:

```html
$(function () {
            $("#OrganizationGrid .details").click(function () {
                var organizationId = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();

                //alert(organizationId)
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Organizations/Details",
                    data: { 'id': organizationId },
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#viewEditOrgModal").find(".modal-body").html(response);
                        $("#viewEditOrgModal").modal('show');
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```